# Powershell object cannot be found with strictmode latest

Tags: powershell, android-strictmode

I am trying to get below to work under `set-strictmode -version latest`, it works completely fine without strict mode, unfortunately it's a requirement to have latest strictmode in my environment.

What it does: go through registry to find the entry with EEELinkAdvertisement and assign it to $findEeeLinkAd

```
$findEeeLinkAd = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'hklm:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | `
   % {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.pspath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | `
  ? {$_.EeeLinkAdvertisement} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

I receive a bunch of the following errors despite running in Administrator:

```
The property 'EEELinkAdvertisement' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:3 char:12
+         ? {$_.EEELinkAdvertisement} }
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note**:

- Unless you're prepared to thoroughly test and each every existing script / function / written-in-PowerShell module every time you upgrade to a new PowerShell version, **I suggest avoiding `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` *in production code*** - it's fine during *development*, but when it comes to publishing code, the then-current highest version should be specified explicitly and thereby locked in. If you don't do that, **existing code may break if and when a new strictness check is introduced in a later PowerShell version**.
- The bottom section shows how to *generally* deal with attempts to access nonexistent properties with strict mode in effect.

You can streamline your code as follows, which implicitly *bypasses* the problem of trying to access a property not present on all input objects:

```bash
$rootKey = 'hklm:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class'

# Find all keys that have a 'EeeLinkAdvertisement' value.
$findEeeLinkAd = 
  Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $rootKey -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore | 
    ForEach-Object { if ($null -ne $_.GetValue('EeeLinkAdvertisement')) { $_ } }
```

<sup>Note the switch from `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `-ErrorAction Ignore`: the latter quietly *discards* any errors, whereas the former *doesn't display them*, but still records them in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error), which is a *session-wide* collection of all (non-ignored) errors.</sup>

This takes advantage of the fact that the [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue) method quietly *ignores* attempts to retrieve data for a nonexistent value and returns `$null`.

As an aside: It is virtually pointless to apply the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction) to the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (`?`) and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (`%`)  cmdlets, because the parameter is *not* applied to the code that runs *inside the script blocks* (`{ ... }`) passed to these commands.

---

#### Avoiding errors when accessing non-existent properties in strict mode:

[`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) with `-Version 2` or higher (including `Latest`) causes attempts to access a nonexistent property on an object to report a *statement-terminating* error.

- Do note that this means that by default only *the statement at hand* is terminated, whereas overall script execution *continues*.
- Also note that `-Off` is the default value; that is, *no* strictness checks are performed by default, which means that even attempts to reference nonexistent *variables* do *not* trigger an error by default; `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` checks for nonexistent *variables*, but not for nonexistent *properties*.

There are several ways of avoiding such errors:

- **Use a [`Try` / `Catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally)** around the property access, as also shown in [CFou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64772332/45375); this also makes it easy to specify a *default value* in the absence of the property, but catching the exception is *slow* compared to the reflection-based approach below:

  ```bash
  $o = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }

  $propValue = try { $o.NoSuchProperty } catch { 'default value' }
  ```
- ***Temporarily* disable strict mode** in a *child scope* (this is about as slow as the `try` / `catch` approach):

  ```bash
  $o = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }

  # $propValue will effectively receive $null.
  # Strictly speaking: [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value
  $propValue = & { Set-StrictMode -Off; $o.NoSuchProperty }
  ```
- **Use *reflection*** to test a property's existence, via the hidden `.psobject.Properties` member available on all objects; this is the *fastest* approach:

  ```bash
  $o = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }

  $propValue = if ($o.psobject.Properties['NoSuchProperty']) { $o.NoSuchProperty }
  ```

In **PowerShell [Core] 7.1+**, you can do this more succinctly, via the [null-conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators?view=powershell-7.1#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```bash
$o = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }

# Note the `?.`, which only tries to access the property if the expression
# to the left isn't $null.
$propValue = $o.psobject.Properties['NoSuchProperty']?.Value
```

- **Pitfall as of v7.1**: If you apply `?.` directly to a *variable*, you must unexpectedly enclose its name in `{...}`, e.g. **`${var}?.Property`**; `$var?.Property` does *not* work as intended, because PowerShell then assumes the variable name is `var?` - see [GitHub issue #11379](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11379) for an attempt to change that.

Similarly, the [null-coalescing operator, `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-operator-) (which itself became available in v7.0) can simplify providing a *default* value (which in earlier versions you can achieve by adding an `else` branch to the `if` statement above):

```bash
$o = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }

# The RHS of `??` is used if the LHS evaluates to $null.
$propValue = $o.psobject.Properties['NoSuchProperty']?.Value ?? 'default value'
```

Comment: thanks you. Been banding my head all night trying to test properties. The docs don't say anything about strictness level. At least not in the docs about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3#testing-for-properties

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @MichaelWelch. I encourage you to suggest improvements to the docs at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues

Answer (score 0):

`EeeLinkAdvertisement` is an undefined property for many items you grab, so this is normal.
You can cheat like this :

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'hklm:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | `
   % {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.pspath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | `
  ? {try{$_.EeeLinkAdvertisement}catch{}} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```